# ASP.Net MVC loading spinner for button click and needs the spinner till the data loads in the screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

### Need to display the loading spinner in the screen till the data loads completely. Currently I used fade in / fade out in javascript. Any one please help me out.

Here is the javascript which is used for displaying the spinner when button click triggered

```
function Loading() {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeIn(10);
    $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(5000);


    var url = '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Home")'

    $("#Load").load(url);

}
```

---

Here is the css that has gif image..

```
        <style type="text/css">
    #dvLoading {
        background: url('../../Content/img/loading.gif') no-repeat;
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1000;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how can we help you with this little information you gave us here mate. be more specific, share code samples etc. let we know what are you really trying to do.